# Validate the proof that $x_n = {\ln n \over n}$ is bounded by $\ln2$ and find $\sup\{x_n\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and:
>   $$
> x_n = \left\{ \ln n \over n \right\}
> $$
>   Prove $x_n$ is bounded by $\ln 2$. Find $\sup\{x_n\}$

Consider nominator and denominator, $\ln n$ is growing slower than $n$ therefore:
$$
{\ln n \over n} <1
$$

Suppose:

$$
{\ln n \over n} < \ln2 \iff \ln n < n\ln2 \iff \ln n < \ln{2^n} \iff n < 2^n
$$

So $n < 2^n$ which is true for any $n \in \mathbb N$

It it valid? And also for the second part how can I find supremum $x_n$ without using calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $n\in \mathbb N$

for some $N>0, n>N \implies \frac {\ln n}{n}> \frac {\ln (n+1)}{n+1}$

Or $n^{n+1} > (n+1)^{n}$

It is not true when $n=2$
as $2^3 = 8 < 9 = 3^2$

But it is true for $n > 2$

sup $x_n = \frac {\ln 3}{3}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain how you find $\sup x_n = {\ln3 \over 3}$?

Comment: There still is a proof to be done that $n>2 \implies n^{n+1} > (n+1)^n$ but that shouldn't be too hard.  Once you have that, and with what is outlined above, that it is not true when $n=2$  then $x_3$ is the maximal value in the sequence.

Comment: many thanks and appreciations